# What's the common strategy to optimize c++ arithmetic computation for arrays?

Tags: c++, c, optimization

For example, I have three `float` arrays, `a`, `b` and `c`, and I want to add `a` and `b` element-wisely up to `c`. A naive way is like

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

As far as I know, `OpenMP` can parallelize this piece of code. In `OpenCV` code, I see some flags like `CV_SSE2` and `CV_NEON` which are related to optimization.

What's the common way to optimize these kinds of code, if I want my code highly efficient?

Comment: I might sound a bit repetitive, but compile, profile and report before overcomplicating! Most compilers are capable of auto vectorization (i.e. using the MMX/SSE capabilities of processors for performing multiple operations in a single issue) and will perform a wide range of loop optimizations. Additionally, the overhead of a OpenMP scheduler might even degrade performance over such a small body.

TL;DR modern CPUs and compilers are pretty smart, don't just assume you need to be smarter. Unless you are not satisfied with the runtime of your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**There is no common strategy**. You should be sure that it is a bottleneck (which it might not be, if the size `n` of your arrays is small enough).

Some compilers are able to [optimize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) that (at least in some simple cases) by using [vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_processor) machine instructions. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) try to compile with `gcc -O3 -mtune=native` (or other `-mtune=`... or `-mfpu=`... arguments, in particular if you are cross-compiling) and possibly `-ffast-math`

You could consider [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP), [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) (with a GPGPU), [OpenACC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenACC), [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface), explicit threading with e.g. [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) or [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) [std::thread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/)-s, etc... (and a clever mix of several approaches)

I would leave the optimization to the compiler, and only consider improving that if you measure that it is a bottleneck. You could spend months or years (or even specialize in that for your whole work life) of your developer time to improve it ....

You could also use some [numerical computation library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_libraries) (e.g. [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/), [GSL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/), etc...) or specialized software like [Scilab](http://scilab.org/), [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), [R](http://www.r-project.org), etc...

Read also http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: On GCC and Clang, try `-march=native` or `-mtune=native` to enable instructions that are specifically available on your hardware...

Comment: Or `-mfpu=neon` etc if you want to be explicit (ARM code is often cross-compiled, and then `-march=native` makes no sense)

Answer (score 1):

You should continue looking into parallel options. But for single-threaded, it's generally faster to do it like this:

```
int i = 0;
for (; i < n - 3; i += 4) {
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
    c[i + 1] = a[i + 1] + b[i + 1];
    c[i + 2] = a[i + 2] + b[i + 2];
    c[i + 3] = a[i + 3] + b[i + 3];
}

for (; i < n; i++) {
    c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
}
```

Sometimes unrolling can be done by the compiler, but at least in my experience (I use MSC), the compiler typically never tries to perform any partial unrolling like this, and sometimes it can help. This can be beneficial when each of the 4 things inside the loop can be pipelined and running in parallel and it saves comparisons/jumps.

So I would use this as a starting point, and measure it. Then, only apply the parallelization if you measure a gain over this. Or, if you make your threads by hand, each thread should probably do the unrolled variant.

Update: I'm not personally seeing any gain from this. I think it's because inside the unrolled loop, a full 12 floats are accessed. And the float operations are likely slow enough to negate any savings from the jge/cmp operations that are eliminated by unrolling it.

Still, whenever you have a similar problem, with lighter, independent operations, I still recommend at least trying this, because it generates clearly different assembly when you unroll it in the code and you'll get some different perf characteristics and reduce the number of cmp/jmp by a factor of 4, which can help but I think the floating point operations are just too significant for this to matter here.

Comment: Harsh words against the compiler -- it's not generally clear that unrolling is a good idea. It's a trade-off, and compilers probably try to decide the trade-off in a way that's acceptable on most code, rather than perfect for one use case. You have to profile and see which amount of unrolling benefits your use case and platform.

Comment: I just verified that the loop is, in fact, not unrolled in MSC unless you do it by hand as shown (by looking at the disassembly). I have measured significant gains from doing this before (~15%), but never with even tried with floats... I'll set up a measurement and see if it really helps or not.

Comment: "I just verified..." with which compiler options enabled / compiler version?

Comment: @VoidStar: To clarify, I don't mean that you can't improve performance for your one use case by hand-tuning it. What I meant is that this isn't generally a "fault" of the compiler. Overall it is probably still generating good code, and if its default strategy were to unroll your loop, it would probably produce a lot of worse code elsewhere.

Comment: Results are in... doesn't help, same measurement either way. The disassembly is completely different in each case though. I suspect two reasons... floats are kind of slow, dwarfing the savings of only doing jge / cmp once. Also, 12 intermediate pointers are necessary to hold a/b/c in an unrolled 4-block way, which is more than usual when I do this. Again, I know this CAN help, so it was at least worth the shot.

Comment: @Tony D Im on dev12 and running with /O2.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by others, there is not the "common strategy" but it really depends on your particular use case: Are the arrays very large? Are they rather small but you have to call this function very frequently? Such question you will have to ask yourself. And before trying to optimize anything, you should always profile your code. In most applications more than 90% of the time is spend in only less than 10% of the code. Unless you know exactly where to find this 10% it can have little to no effect to optimize parts of the application.

However, when it is about arithmetic computations, I think it is always a good start to rely on the optimized standard algorithms. When concerned about efficiency, I would add two arrays (after putting a and b in a std::vector or std::array and preallocating c) via

```
std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(),c.begin(), std::plus<float>());
```

Comment: "When concerned about efficiency" - well, preallocate in `c` and get rid of `back_inserter`...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath good point. Actually I just copied this line from somewhere else and didnt pay attention to the details. Shame on me

Answer (score -2):

Depending on your compiler's optimization stage an array index `a[i]`may be slower than a pointer dereference  `*p` (with p incremented in each iteration so `p = a+i`)

So without relying on the optimizer this *may be* faster with some compilers:

```
float* pa = a;
float* pb = b;
float* pc = c;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    *pc++ = *pa++ + *pb++;
```

While it may seem trivial in this case, this basic technique can result in large gains in more complicated cases where things are too complicated for the optimizer to do the job.

Comment: Can you provide a real example where `a[i]` and `*(a+i)` produce different machine code?

Comment: It can be often wrong, but still worth benchmarking if someone cares (but not enough to thread it, resort to assembly or another library).  Not an unreasonable answer.

Comment: @TonyD: The language rules say that `a[i]` is *defined as* (and therefore identical to) `*(a + i)`, so yes, lacking actual evidence, I'd call this an unreasonable answer. What next, `int main(int, char**)` is slower than `int main(int, char*[])`?

Comment: I edited my answer, now its *p, which is surely faster than a[i]

Comment: @DrKoch: I was happy to see the edit (which is reasonable) right until you said "is surely faster" (which is not). Please accompany your claims with at least one real example assembly output.

Comment: @DrKoch: most optimizing compilers would often transform your code into the equivalent of `for (int i=0; i<n; i++) c[i] = a[i] + b[i];` and then emit vectorizing instructions. So you are really wrong.

Comment: @Kerrek I changed to "may be faster" to stop religuous wars here

Comment: @KerrekSB: *"`a[i]` is defined as `*(a + i)`"* that misses the point: the most literal / unoptimised evaluation of the address of `a[i]` or `*(a + i)` is as `&a` plus a runtime *multiplication* of `i` by `sizeof *a`, whereas the pointer incrementing in this answer involves additions by the constant `sizeof *a`; this is such an old issue that modern optimisers are almost certain to general the same optimal code whichever way it's written, but there's no actual harm in proving that to yourself if you've reason to care - strange things can occasionally prevent optimisations kicking in.

Comment: FWIW, I never saw the answer before it said "may be faster", and actively checked the edit history to see whether the "may" had been there in the original answer, but given DrKock's "I changed..." obviously SO's merged the edit into the first version.  The "may" is critical to this answer being vaguely reasonable....

Comment: [Example](http://goo.gl/KsmRYh) (with `-O2`). Indeed, with `-O0` there's a difference, but when you ask about performance microtuning, presumably compiler optimizations are allowed? The true answer to the OP's question seems to be "tell the compiler to optimize", rather than fudge your code.